# How to find programatically that hard keyboard is popped out in android device

Tags: android

I am an android developer. I am developing one application for a samsung device which supports hard keyboard. In this application, I have to change the orientation of my application only when hard keyboard is popped out as well as Editview is focused.

Can anyone please help me to find the solution of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Basically, define in your Manifest that your activity will handle keyboard|orientation changes. So, in the Manifest, check Config changes that you want to handle yourself. And override this function to handle the changes

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{

}
```